# How to compare fields in Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have a very very large amount of data that I need to analyze in Excel. 1 million rows by 10+ columns. I have huge problems regarding processing time when I copy down formulas to make comparisons between data in different sorted rows so I am wondering if I could use a pivot table or if some other function would make processing more efficient. ie say I have sorted column A which is date and Column B which is hour and I want to compare Column C which is temperature in any row to that which is say 2 hours previously and 2 hours later etc.

Comment: You can set the calculations to run manually on the `Formulas` tab. However you might need to consider a better software solution for the large datasets, eg. getting the database server to pre-process and generate the data in the needed format.